# How to speed up an endpoint that's passing a significant amount of data to db

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, endpoint

Essentially I have a React web app that I'm creating to upload a large set of data to a db. As of now I'm using a test file that's only around 3000 lines long and the total time to upload all the data from the file is around 4 minutes. I need to speed this up significantly but I'm not totally sure how. For reference the actual size of files I plan to upload will be around 100k lines long. Also another issue that I'm pretty sure I can fix with a little tinkering is I start to run out of net resources around 80k request so if there are any suggestions to modifying my delayQue function to avoid that then it would be appreciated as well.

Test file size: 76kb

Real file size: 5 mb

Endpoint

```
  const stepData = async() =>{

    const body = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
    assignToBody(body)

    try{

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/stepdata',{
                method:"POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })}catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    
}
```

Throttle (note: assignVals just assigns the values to the body in my endpoint)

```
    const delayQue = () =>{

        assignVals(row)
        row++
        
        if(row % 500 == 0){
            setTimeout(delayQue,2000)
        }else{
            setTimeout(delayQue,100)
        }
    
  }
```

also another thing incase its important each line contains anywhere from 6 to 20 points of data. I lowered my number of calls by assigning the values to an object and passing the object. Any help on speeding this up will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
To clarify the issue is that I am simply having to make 100k request or more and am trying to find a way to speed up my request or at least manage them better instead of using settimeout and embedded try and catches.

Update:
I'm fairly certain the issue is a resouce leak in my endpoint

Comment: uploading isn't the problem, processing it, inserting everything in your db and waiting for a response is what's taking time. Instead why not just upload the file and don't wait for a response, let the DB do its job in the background. Otherwise you may want to optimize your DB and code for performance, maybe use something like a NoSQL database if you aren't already.

Comment: Deepak's comment is on the money. It's entirely possible the upload is also part of the issue though. `3000 lines` doesn't specify file size in any way, just the number of `\n` newlines. You need to profile the workflow and determine where the waiting is actually happening to decide what to optimize. Often times telling the user "okay thanks for teh data" and then processing in the background is a good solution that doesn't require much actual optimization to improve the user experience a lot.

Comment: I appreciate the input just for a clarification I am currently using a postgres db. I'm fairly certain the slowness is coming from the responses as you said. So I suppose my question is how do I help my responses resolve quicker. The reason for that is that there is a massive amount of data that needs to be uploaded and the faster its uploaded the better. Also I edited the file size above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the amount of data transferred over the network:

File size can be reduced very efficiently using a compression algorithm like gzip or brotli.
Depending on the webserver you are using you will have to activate compression first for it to be used.

Here a example how to use with express:
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/compression.html

Depending on the data you want to transfer, you can reduce the file size significantly. Repetitive text files compress best. Already compressed files like jpeg images don't compress at all.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong because I could of totally misinterpreted the answer you've given. This would help with uploading files directly? If so I'm sorry for not making my issue clear enough. My issue isn't the file size its that after parsing the file I am having to make a large amount of post request and they are taking a long time to resolve. So I'm looking to see if there is a way to speed that part of the process up.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't get that. No if the problem is the sheer amount of requests this technique won't help you.

Comment: Maybe try using http2 or even better using a bi-directional connection with webrtc.